# Creating scorer for Brier Score Loss in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to make use of GridSearchCV and RandomizedSearchCV in scikit-learn (0.16.1) for logistic regression and random forest classifiers (and possibly others down the road) for binary class problems. I managed to get GridSearchCV to work with the standard LogisticRegression classifier, but I cannot get LogisticRegressionCV to work (or RandomizedGridCV for the RandomForestClassifier) with a customized scoring function, specifically brier_score_loss. I have tried this code:

```
lrcv = LogisticRegressionCV(scoring = make_scorer(brier_score_loss, greater_is_better=False, needs_proba=True, needs_threshold=False, pos_label=1))
lrcv_clf = lrcv.fit(X=X_train,y=y_train)
```

But I keep getting errors that are essentially saying the brier_score_loss function is receiving input (y_prob) with 2 columns, causing an error (bad input shape). Is there a way to specify to use only the second column of y_prob (lrcv.predict_proba) so that the Brier score can be calculated in this way? I thought pos_label might help but apparently not. Do I need to avoid make_scorer and just create my own scoring function?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`predict_proba` returns two probabilities for every predicted `y` value, the first is about `0` and the second is about `1`. You should choose which one you need and pass it further to the scoring function.
I'm doing this with the simple proxy function:

```
def ProbaScoreProxy(y_true, y_probs, class_idx, proxied_func, **kwargs):
    return proxied_func(y_true, y_probs[:, class_idx], **kwargs)
```

That can be used like this:

```
scorer = metrics.make_scorer(ProbaScoreProxy, greater_is_better=False, needs_proba=True, class_idx=1, proxied_func=metrics.brier_score_loss)
```

For the binary classification the `class_idx` can be 0 or 1.

Comment: Why do I get negative values? with GridSearchCV and RandomizedSearchCV and cross_val_score? it seems that the best value is the lower negative value.... @arabesc

Comment: @Javiss I am also getting negative values with my brier score. Did you find out what was happening?